# Android: Array index when i first click the button it doesn't show my first index but it show the second index

Tags: android

I'm creating an app on android for viewing the image with the sound.I got problem when i first click the next button it doesn't show the my first index image with sound but it show my second index. i want to show my first index when i first click on the next button.

```
   public void btn_click(View v){
  ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewPreview3);
  if (v == btn_next) {
          try {
              currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
              currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + 1) % myMusic.length;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }
  if (v == btn_back) {
          try {
              currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + IMAGE_IDS.length - 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
              currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + myMusic.length - 1) % myMusic.length;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }
  imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
  mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
  mp.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Then maybe you want to initially set `currentimageindex ` to -1 since you are adding one to it (though be careful if you are using it anywhere else). Or use some flag to see if you haven't shown the first one yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use equals(Object) instead of ==

```
if (v.equals(btn_next)) {
          try {
              currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
              currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + 1) % myMusic.length;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }
```

and so on.

Comment: in this case, `==` works, because the views really are the same object.